# How do I make an HTML button connect to a Javascript function for HTML5 Canvas to make the Spaceship Fire

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the game Asteroids, written in vanilla javascript. I'm trying to make the game interactive for Touchscreens and Mouse Pointers..so i'm thinking just add some html buttons to accomplish that.  But my buttons won't do anything. Please help as I've tried for 3 weeks and no luck.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);

// event listeners
function keyDown( /** @type [KeyboardEvent] */ ev) {
  if (ship.dead) {
    return;
  }

  switch (ev.key) {
    case "ArrowDown":
    case " ": // spacebar key
    case "Down":
      // case 32:  // spacebar (shoot lasers)
      shootLaser();
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft": // Keyboard Compatibility 
    case "Left": // IE Compatibility
      // case 37:  // left arrow (rotate ship left)
      ship.rot = TURN_SPEED / 180 * Math.PI / FPS;
      break;
    case "ArrowUp": // Keyboard Compatibility 
    case "Up": // IE Compatibility
      // case 38: // up arrow (thrust the ship forward)
      ship.thrusting = true;
      break;
      // case "KeyD":
    case "ArrowRight":
    case "Right":
      // case 39:  // right arrow (rotate ship right)
      ship.rot = -TURN_SPEED / 180 * Math.PI / FPS;
      break;
  }
}

function keyUp( /** @type [KeyboardEvent] */ ev) {
  if (ship.dead) {
    return;
  }

  switch (ev.key) {
    case "ArrowDown":
    case " ": // spacebar key
    case "Down": // down arrow (for one handed accessibility controls)
      // case 32:  // spacebar (allow shooting again)
      ship.canShoot = true;
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft": // Keyboard Compatibility 
    case "Left": // IE Compatibility
      // case 37:  // left arrow (stop rotate ship left)
      ship.rot = 0;
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
    case "Up":
      // case 38:  // up arrow (stop thrusting)
      ship.thrusting = false;
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
    case "Right":
      // case 39:  // right arrow (stop rotate ship right)
      ship.rot = 0;
      break;
  }
}
```

and here is what I'm trying to get working but i'm running out of hair to pull out:

in html file:

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" name="btn-left-arrow" id="btn-left-arrow"><</button>
  <button type="button" name="btn-up-arrow" id="btn-up-arrow">^</button>
  <button type="button" name="btn-right-arrow" id="btn-right-arrow">></button>
  <button type="button" name="btn-down-arrow" id="btn-down-arrow">v</button>
  <button type="button" name="btnSpace" id="btnSpace">Shoot</button>
  <button onclick="shootLaser()">Shoot</button>
  <input id="btnSpace" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="shootLaser();" />
</div>
```

in js file:

```
<button onclick="shootLaser()">Shoot</button>
```

I have tried so many different things and nothing has working, I'm going insane...please help!

I probably don't need all these extra lines of code, but I'm almost out of deadline time and I'm trying everything.

even just to get the Shoot button to work would be a major hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a canvas in HTML, there is an area rendered where you can draw with the available api's of canvas. So when you want to capture a `click` event (or any other event available) on a canvas you will have to capture the click event on the `<canvas>` HTML element, since its a HTML element it has got the click event firing when you click on the canvas, something like

```js
function canvasClick($event) {
  console.log('canvas was clicked:')
  console.log(`X:${$event.clientX}, Y: ${$event.clientY}`)
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200px" height="200px" onclick="canvasClick(event)"></canvas>
```

Now when you have the listener for the canvas, you will have to figure out with the help of the click position whether it was clicked on the required object or not. You can calculate that based on the relative position of the canvas i.e (consider top left as origin 0,0 of canvas) and when you create the object keep this things in stored in a variable where you can refer it calculate the position based on this find out if the object clicked was the required one and then handle accordingly.

Or you can go for some of the Canvas libraries as those libraries provide you with lot of such things and makes it easy to work with canvas. Check out [Fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/) or [Threejs](https://threejs.org/)